# Return angular asset with content type application/json (Android deep link)

Tags: json, angular, assets, android-deep-link

so i'm trying to enable deep links for my android app, my app is actually an angular app that uses ionic's capacitor.So i generated a assetlinks.json on https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator and put it in my angular app under a .well-known folder, and then i added it to my assets array.
So now when i go to that link i can successfully see my json, the problem is that it shows as html. It's html with the json text inside it. Because of that google can't find it...

So in short, how can i return a json when visiting a URL on angular like: mydomain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
instead of html with the json text in it?

Comment: are you getting it with http client?

Comment: what do you mean? i can't get it to work with https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator when pressing "Test statement"